# Passing data, file and path param in a single call to REST API

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have been working in REST Apis, and is trying to get the following working,  here is what I need,

I want to post the file, the appId, and some extra JSON data in the same call, so for instance my call would by something like

```
@POST
@Path(app/{appId}/test)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response postConnectIos(@PathParam("appId") String appId, 
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileIS){
      /*
       Code of handle here
      */
}
```

This code works and I am able to get the file content by reading the stream as well as able to get the appId Path param as well, but I want to achieve this as

```
@POST
@Path(app/{appId}/test)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response postConnectIos(@PathParam("appId") String appId, 
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileIS,
        MyRequest request){
      /*
       Code of handle here
      */
}
```

Now MyRequest is basically a simple class with one field name, so if my understandings are correct, in order to call this api user has to call something in this fashion,

Post the **file data** to **blah_server/app/1234/test**, with the form data as :

```
{"name":"test"}
```

But as and when I make this function with extra parameter of the **MyRequest** my code starts failing, server throws an error saying:

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response blah blah 
*Please check [here][1]*
```

So my questions are:

1. Is the thing I am asking possible, if yes, then how?
2. How do I solve my problem if this can't be done the way I am thinking, how can I get the data in my function?

Thanks in advance..